# What is "corrective discipline"?

Tags: meaning

What does "corrective discipline" mean in the following passage?

> Though the pleasure which works of art give us must not be confused with other pleasures that we enjoy, it is related to all of them simply by being our pleasure and not someone else's. All the judgments, aesthetic or moral, that we pass, however objective we try to make them, are in part a rationalization and in part a **corrective discipline** of our subjective wishes.
>
> So long as a man writes poetry or fiction, his dream of Eden is his own business, but the moment he starts writing literary criticism, honesty demands that he describe it to his readers, so that they may be in the position to judge his judgments.
>
> <sup>—From W.H. Auden, "Reading," in *The Dyer's Hand and Other Essays* (1956).</sup>

Does *discipline* here mean *training* or *restraint/control* or something else?

Comment: It's a euphemism for "punishment".

Comment: @HotLicks No it's not, and actually reading the quote in the question would make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Corrective* discipline could imply that such action is aimed to correct any behaviour that might cause disruption. These behaviours or violations may be a first-level violation that does not immediately cause disruption, but a violation that need to be corrected to prevent repetition, mitigate escalation. Juxtapose it with the idea of a *punitive* discipline which is an action aimed to punish a person for a more aggravated/escalated violations

Answer (score -1):

"Corrective discipline" is a euphemism for "punishment".

Comment: 'Corrective discipline' intended to be 'corrective', i.e. prevent some behaviour. 'Punishment' is retribution, which is very different.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Dictionaries do not always convey the true meanings of words.  Hans Adler above states "Corrective discipline is normally a euphemism for child abuse."  He is correct.

Comment: As was pointed out to Hans Adler, if you Google "corrective discipline" you will find all the top usages are in a workplace or tertiary education context describing "corrective discipline" for managers and administrators. They are not describing how to perform child abuse. There are people who beat children and call it 'corrective discipline", but it's an abuse of the term.

Comment: @DJClayworth: See PS to my answer. Today's top Google hits aren't very relevant for what this phrase meant to people in 1956.